# Как сделать URL динамического сайта вот таким?

Tags: html, веб-программирование, url

Как на динамических сайтах (Да, вопрос от новичка) делают вид URL вот таким:

```
https://site.ru/kak-sdelat-vid-url-takim
```

Вместо такого:

```
https://site.ru/post.php?id=14
```

И какие изменения при этом происходят в структуре сайта и его БД? Зачем это делается? Только для красоты, и для того, чтобы было при первом взгляде на ссылку сразу видно, куда она ведет?

Comment: Почитайте про ЧПУ (человеко понятная УРЛ)
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_URL

Если в кратце - то сайт настраивается таким образом что все url ведут на обработчик запроса. Обработчик запроса пробует найти эту урл в базе. после чего она пробразовывется внутри в "/post.php?id=14" (это грубо говоря) ну и дальше обрабатывается. Или отдается 404 - если совпадений не найдено

Answer (score 0):

Все зависит от того что вы используете на стороне сервера, например для RoR, которым я пользуюсь , есть gem 'friendly-id', который заменяет запись ?Id=1 в URL на содержимое поля в БД которое я указываю, например "/some-text-in-field"